# C# Grouping hours by week to find total hours when stored in a child

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grouping

This is working great when **not** referencing the child records.

I am getting the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool'

at:

```
.Select((g, i) => new
```

Thanks in advance!

```
var weekGroups = item.TaskActions
    .All(z => z.TaskActionDurations
        .Where(c => c.TimeStart >= beginReportDate)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.TimeStart)
        .Select(p => new
        {
            TaskActionDurations = p,
            Hours = p.Hours,
            Year = p.TimeStart.Value.Year.ToString(),
            Week = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                p.TimeStart.Value, 
                System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, 
                System.DayOfWeek.Monday)
        })
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Week })
        .Select((g, i) => new
        {
            WeekGroup = g,
            WeekNum = i + 1,
            Year = g.Key.Year,
            CalendarWeek = g.Key.Week,
            Count = g.Count(),
            Hours = g.Sum(s => s.Hours),
            WorkOrderHours = g.Where(w => w.TaskActionDurations.TaskAction.Task.WorkOrders.Any())
                .Sum(s => s.Hours)
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely happening because you're not queering everything for multiple results and that causes this.

Switch it up so that it will give the result and not expect one output only.

EDIT: you might want to try Select instead of All, also, you should have at least tried doing some research on why this could have happened.

Answer (score 0):

`All` takes a predicate function, given an argument returns a `BOOL`, so your function taking `z` returns an `IEnumerable` of anonymous  type instead, maybe you wanted `Select` instead of `All` in your first statement.

Comment: Actually it's returning an `IEnumerable` of anonymous classes instead of a bool.

Answer (score 0):

The `.All` is expecting a `Func<T,bool>`, but you are giving it a lambda expression that returns an `IEnumerable` of anonymous classes.  It's not obvious what you're trying to accomplish, but you might want to change the `All` to a `SelectMany`.  That will flatten the `IEnumerable`s you create in your lambda down to one `IEnumerable` vs. using `Select` that would give you an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<anonymousClass>>`